# find matching values in list of dictionaries and pair the strings

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I'm having trouble coming up with a code piece that will do what I want.

I have a list of dictionaries that use this structure:

`word = {'word': 'Dog', 'loc': 160}`

They are appended to a list in a for loop:

```
words = []

for line in lines:
  word = {'word': line['WordText'], 'loc': line['Location']}
  ...
  words.append(word)
```

Every line has a `location` integer, and I need to pair the text with the line later on.

I need to find all the instances where the value for key `loc` matches in the list, then pair them up somehow.

(Python) pseudo-code:

```
new_lines = []

for word in words:
  new_line = {'line': '', 'loc': 0}
  if a_word['loc'] == another_word['loc']:
    new_line['line'] = a_word['word'] + another_word['word']
    new_line['loc'] = a_word['loc']
    new_lines.append(new_line)
```

I know that isn't the right approach, but I need some kind of `if any word['loc'] matches any other word['loc']: then put into list` kind of thing.

In case it wasn't clear, I want to pair up the *words* in the dictionaries where the *loc* value matches.

Comment: What is your objective ? Are you trying to find pairs of lines that have some words in common ? Or do you intend to find all lines that contain a certain word ?  The former could generate an inordinate amount of combinations.  The latter would be much easier

Comment: @AlainT. please see my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a dictionary where each location collects a list of words. Then filter out locations that only have one word.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lines = [{'WordText': 'dog',   'Location': 11},
         {'WordText': 'cow',   'Location': 222},
         {'WordText': 'cat',   'Location': 11},
         {'WordText': 'horse', 'Location': 222},
         {'WordText': 'duck',  'Location': 55},
         {'WordText': 'goat',  'Location': 222}]

wordsAtLoc = defaultdict(set)
for line in lines:
    wordsAtLoc[line['Location']].add(line['WordText'])
matches = { loc:list(words) for loc,words in wordsAtLoc.items() if len(words)>1 }   

print(matches)
# {11: ['cat', 'dog'], 222: ['goat', 'horse', 'cow']}
```

Comment: great, and it works even if there's more than one word for a location.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to find all the instances where the value for key loc matches in the list, then pair them up somehow.

Use default dict to group the words by 'loc'.

with this you can iterate over 'd' and do what you like to do.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

words = [{'word': 'fog', 'loc': 12}, {'word': 'bird', 'loc': 122}, {'word': 'bag', 'loc': 12},
         {'word': 'main', 'loc': 33}]

for word in words:
    d[word['loc']].append(word['word'])
print(d)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {12: ['fog', 'bag'], 122: ['bird'], 33: ['main']})
```